# Select column pairs into a variable pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, tuples

I am having a tupleset that I re-use multiple times:

```
with ICC_DATA_REQS AS
(
 select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req from TRANEMV2G where msg_type = 'CQ' and (BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID) IN (
                SELECT BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID
                FROM TRANRSP2G
                WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1)
),

ICC_DATA_RESP AS 
(
select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_rsp from TRANEMV2G where msg_type = 'CS' and (BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID) IN (
                SELECT BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID
                FROM TRANRSP2G
                WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1)
),
ICC_DATA_ADVC AS 
(
select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, orig_ml_tran_id, icc_data as icc_data_adv from TRANEMV2G where msg_type = 'CA' and (BUSINESS_DT, ORIG_ML_TRAN_ID) IN (
                SELECT BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID
                FROM TRANRSP2G
                WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1)
)
```

What I am trying to do is :

```
SELECT BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID INTO vpairs
                FROM TRANRSP2G
                WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1
```

And then use the vpairs in the other queries. Is this possible? I keep running into unknown variable errors.

Also, the reason I am doing this whole thing is the table TRANEMV2G has 3 records, and I need data from 3 records as 3 columns. I couldn't find a better way of doing this.

Comment: If you specifically want a PL/SQL approach, how have you defined/declared `vpairs` - as a record type, or object type; with a table or varray type?

Answer (score 3):

You could retrieve them in another CTE:

```
with p2g as
(
  select business_dt, ml_tran_id
  from tranrsp2g
  where settle_file_id = -1
),
icc_data_reqs as
(
  select v2g.ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req
  from p2g
  join tranemv2g v2g
  on v2g.business_dt = p2g.business_dt
  and v2g.ml_tran_id = p2g.ml_tran_id
  where v2g.msg_type = 'CQ'
),
icc_data_resp as 
(
  select v2g.ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_rsp
  from p2g
  join tranemv2g v2g
  on v2g.business_dt = p2g.business_dt
  and v2g.ml_tran_id = p2g.ml_tran_id
  where v2g.msg_type = 'CS'
),
icc_data_advc as 
(
  select v2g.ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, orig_ml_tran_id, icc_data as icc_data_adv
  from p2g
  join tranemv2g v2g
  on v2g.business_dt = p2g.business_dt
  and v2g.orig_ml_tran_id = p2g.ml_tran_id
  where v2g.msg_type = 'CA'
)
```

or

```
with p2g as
(
  select business_dt, ml_tran_id
  from tranrsp2g
  where settle_file_id = -1
),
icc_data_reqs as
(
  select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req
  from tranemv2g
  where msg_type = 'CQ'
  and (business_dt, ml_tran_id) in (select business_dt, ml_tran_id from p2g)
),
icc_data_resp as 
(
  select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_rsp
  from tranemv2g
  where msg_type = 'CS'
  and (business_dt, ml_tran_id) in (select business_dt, ml_tran_id from p2g)
),
icc_data_advc as 
(
  select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, orig_ml_tran_id, icc_data as icc_data_adv
  from tranemv2g
  where msg_type = 'CA'
  and (business_dt, orig_ml_tran_id) in (select business_dt, ml_tran_id from p2g)
)
```

Not sure either is much better than what you have.

If you wanted to a PL/SQL variable then because you want to use it in a SQL context it would need to be a SQL-level type:

```
create type t_tuple as object (business_dt date, ml_tran_id number)
/
create type t_tuple_tab as table of t_tuple
/

declare
    v_tuples t_tuple_tab;
begin
    select t_tuple(business_dt, ml_tran_id)
    bulk collect into v_tuples
    from tranrsp2g
    where settle_file_id = -1;

    with icc_data_reqs as
    (
      select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req
      from tranemv2g
      where msg_type = 'CQ'
      and (business_dt, ml_tran_id) in
        (select business_dt, ml_tran_id from table(v_tuples))
    ),
    ...
```

or joining to the table collection expression. That doesn't seem to gain you much over your original code or using an extra CTE, unless you're going to be reusing the list of tuples again later in your code.

But if I understand what you're doing, you can query the tables once and pivot the result, at least if you're on 11g or above:

```
select * from
(
  select v2g.ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, orig_ml_tran_id, icc_data
  from tranrsp2g p2g
  join tranemv2g v2g
  on v2g.business_dt = p2g.business_dt
  and ((v2g.msg_type in ('CQ', 'CS') and v2g.ml_tran_id = p2g.ml_tran_id)
    or (v2g.msg_type = 'CA' and v2g.orig_ml_tran_id = p2g.ml_tran_id))
  where p2g.settle_file_id = -1
)
pivot (max(icc_data) for (msg_type) in ('CQ' as req, 'CS' as rsp, 'CA' as adv))
```

Comment: I just figured, if I have the tuples as variables, I won't have to query it again.

Comment: If you only need them in this query then the CTE achieves that. (Unless the pivot does what you need). If you need them again later then it might be worth using a collection. Depends how expensive it is to requery, given the data will be in cache anyway.

Comment: Rather than `(business_dt, ml_tran_id) in (select business_dt, ml_tran_id from table(v_tuples))` you could do `t_tuple(business_dt, ml_tran_id) MEMBER OF v_tuples`.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If these are constant values then you can store them in a package:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANRSP2G (
  BUSINESS_DT    DATE,
  ML_TRAN_ID     INT,
  SETTLE_FILE_ID INT
);

CREATE TYPE TRANRSP2G_PAIR IS OBJECT(
  BUSINESS_DT DATE,
  ML_TRAN_ID  INT
);
/
CREATE TYPE TRANRSP2G_PAIR_TABLE IS TABLE OF TRANRSP2G_PAIR;
/

CREATE PACKAGE TRANRSP2G_DATA AS
  FUNCTION getData RETURN TRANRSP2G_PAIR_TABLE;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY TRANRSP2G_DATA AS
  pairs TRANRSP2G_PAIR_TABLE;

  FUNCTION getData RETURN TRANRSP2G_PAIR_TABLE
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN pairs;
  END;

BEGIN
  SELECT TRANRSP2G_PAIR( BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID )
  BULK COLLECT INTO pairs
  FROM TRANRSP2G
  WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1;
END;
/
```

*(Note: the `pairs` collection will be populated when the package is loaded and the data stored there will remain static [even if the underlying tables change] so you should not use this method for non-static data.)*

Then you can do:

```
WITH ICC_DATA_REQS AS
(
  select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req
  from TRANEMV2G
  where msg_type = 'CQ'
  and   TRANRSP2G_PAIR(BUSINESS_DT, ML_TRAN_ID)
          MEMBER OF TRANRSP2G_DATA.getData()
),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values from TRANRSP2G (for SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1) are not too large when concatenated then the list can be fetched once used elsewhere.

LISTAGG is an option. (or other methods as described here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)

```
SELECT LISTAGG(BUSINESS_DT || '_p_' || ML_TRAN_ID, ';')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BUSINESS_DT || '_x_' || ML_TRAN_ID)
INTO vpairs
FROM TRANRSP2G
WHERE SETTLE_FILE_ID = -1;
```

And then vpairs can be used with INSTR

```
select ml_tran_id, tran_type, msg_type, icc_data as icc_data_req 
from TRANEMV2G where msg_type = 'CQ' 
and INSTR(vpairs, BUSINESS_DT || '_x_' || ML_TRAN_ID) <> 0
```

Comment: The values are close to 300,000 records. Would you know if LISTAGG can handle this?

Comment: 300K is big number. Even with clob the limit is 32K chars. Alex and MT0 answers are probably better in this scenario. If you are still interested to use listagg or similar function then look here (search within page for clob): https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:2196162600402